# Flashing and closing PyS60 SIS

Tags: pys60, sis

I created a py script for S60 2nd Edition FP3 with a background image, database, sound files which are stored in a folder on c drive. After several hours, I have managed to convert it into sis which I sent to my mobile phone.

First, I installed the sis on the external memory and it failed to work. I read online that it should be on the same drive as python runtime. So I installed it on phone memory but it just flashes and then closes.

I made another sis with a database and it worked so I suspect it could be because it cant find the background image and sound files in the folder. How can I know the cause of this? Also, how can I include the background image and sound files with the sis so that they are automatically installed when installing the sis file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the exact location of the media files inside the script.

And I think that some SIS packers allow to add files inside SIS.

Comment: Yes, I specified the exact location and it works fine in the emulator with the emulator.

I am using py2sis to convert the py to sis. How do I specify them?